# Serve my website from different server during downtime

Tags: domain-name-system

I have a VPS server running in the cloud. Fully automated server image upgrade/downgrade(by RAM/HDD plans).

The problem is that server upgrade/downgrade takes time and involves total unavailability during this period(up to 30 minutes).

**Goal:** during this downtime server my website(http://mydomain.here) from different server with some message like "Under construction".

How can I do this?

--

mydomain.here is hosted on godaddy and uses its DNS(If I call it right). It's pointing with A-record to my VPS's IP address now.

Change in these DNS settings will take more than 30minutes, so it's not an option. How can I find mode "dynamic" DNS? What should I learn?

Answer (score 4):

what's your budget to achieve this? can you afford having two servers and 'floating' ip address that is assigned to the active node?

say you have 80.1.2.3 permanently assigned to 'fat' machine serving your actual content; you use this ip just for management. 80.1.2.4 bound to machine that only role is to display your 'we will be back soon'-page. and 80.1.2.5 assigned to active node.

with [heartbeat](http://www.linux-ha.org/) you can even automate assignment of floating ip to the right node so in case of crash of primary server the other machine will get it automatically.

ps. your virtual hosting provider will need to support such scenario. [some of them do](http://www.ovh.ie/items/ip_failover.xml) at least for dedicated machines, but i see no technical reasons not to support it for vps'es too.

ps. and yes you can fiddle with dns but it's just wrong [ in my personal, humble opinion ]. there are plenty of operators that provide you with the administrative panel which allows you to set cache lifetime of dns answers.

Comment: +1 - DNS changes is not the answer.